# Reading different encoding from the same InputStream

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, utf-8, stream

For some reason, I want to decode characters of different encodings (say UTF-8 and UTF-16) from the same InputStream.  Please see the following (example) code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] b = new byte[] { (byte) 0xE4, (byte) 0xB8, (byte) 0x96,
            (byte) 0xE7, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0x8C};

    byte[] b1 = new byte[] {(byte) 0x5E, (byte) 0xE3,
        (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x49,  
        (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x2C, (byte) 0x9E,(byte) 0x97 };

    byte[] b2 = new byte[] { (byte) 0xE4, (byte) 0xB8, (byte) 0x96,
        (byte) 0xE7, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0x8C, (byte) 0x5E, (byte) 0xE3,
        (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x49,  
        (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x2C, (byte) 0x9E,(byte) 0x97 };

    ByteArrayInputStream bs = null;
    InputStreamReader ir = null;

    System.out.println("Part 1:");
    bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
    ir = new InputStreamReader(bs, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println((char) ir.read());
    System.out.println((char) ir.read());
    bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(b1);
    ir = new InputStreamReader(bs, "UTF-16");
    System.out.println((char) ir.read());
    System.out.println((char) ir.read());
    System.out.println((char) ir.read());
    System.out.println((char) ir.read());

    System.out.println("Part 2:");
    bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(b2);
    ir = new InputStreamReader(bs, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println((char) ir.read());
    System.out.println((char) ir.read());
    ir = new InputStreamReader(bs, "UTF-16");
    System.out.println((char) ir.read());
    System.out.println((char) ir.read());
    System.out.println((char) ir.read());
    System.out.println((char) ir.read());

}
```

The first part correctly displays the characters, but the second part does not decode the remaining UTF-16 characters in variable b2 (which uses a single InputStream to read a mix of UTF-8 and UTF-16 chars).  As such b2 is concatenation of b and b1 variables.

Any ideas ? Or is taking over a partly read stream forbidden?

Edit:
I am pasting the output for what its worth. It doesn't display the actual characters here, but it does display them when I run eclipse:

```
Part 1:
\u4e16
\u754c
\u5ee3
\u8449
\u842c
\u9e97
Part 2:
\u4e16
\u754c
\uffff
\uffff
\uffff
\uffff
```

Comment: What is the received output of each part? My concern is that it can not be done reliably as the JavaDoc states: "To enable the efficient conversion of bytes to characters, more bytes may be read ahead from the underlying stream than are necessary to satisfy the current read operation."

Comment: When I pasted the output for each part here, it converted it into encoded strings like \uxxxx. It did not display the actual output in Chinese, so I omitted it. I am including the output by editing my post. I don't think it is duplicate as marked by Soltirios Delimanolis. It is close, but my question relates to changing the encoding of the stream in between.

Comment: The \uffff is a special value meaning you have encountered the end of the input stream. Which enforces my first thought that the first reader has read all characters and buffered them. Can you try to replace the 'read()' with 'read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)'?

Comment: Great.. using read(char[], int, int) worked.. Now part1 and part2 are displaying the same thing.. Only thing I am worried is whether I go ahead using this solution or not.. it might stop working for a future JDK..  Thanks @cvesters. Do you want to reply, so that I can upvote and mark it as correct answer?

Comment: I can't answer this question anymore as it has been marked as duplicate.